# Android app crashes after changing package name in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have changed my package name by using the refactor method it was org.something.appname I changed it to org.hd.ghost as it was supposed to be done but still the app crashes. Please help me what am I doing wrong and what can I do to correct it?

P.S- Project doesn't uses Gradle.

[image]

[image]

structure2

[image]

[secondaryactivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihyFY.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
```

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" android:logo="@drawable/ic_logo_w" android:name="org.hd.ghost.VLCApplication" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC.NoTitleBar">
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="org.hd.ghost.gui.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="org.hd.gui.SecondaryActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC"/>
    <activity android:name="org.hd.ghost.gui.CompatErrorActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="org.hd.ghost.gui.PreferencesActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/mediafiles" android:name="org.hd.ghost.gui.BrowserActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC"/>
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="org.hd.ghost.gui.DebugLogActivity"/>
    <service android:name="org.hd.ghost.gui.DebugLogService" android:process=":logger"/>
    <activity android:name="org.hd.ghost.gui.NativeCrashActivity" android:process=":NativeCrashActivity" android:stateNotNeeded="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="org.hd.ghost.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC.Player">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtmp"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtmpe"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtmps"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtp"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtsp"/>
            <data android:scheme="mms"/>
            <data android:scheme="mmsh"/>
            <data android:scheme="icyx"/>
            <data android:scheme="httplive"/>
            <data android:scheme="udp"/>
            <data android:scheme="ghost"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtmp"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtmpe"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtmps"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtp"/>
            <data android:scheme="rtsp"/>
            <data android:scheme="mms"/>
            <data android:scheme="mmsh"/>
            <data android:scheme="icyx"/>
            <data android:scheme="httplive"/>
            <data android:scheme="udp"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:scheme="ftp"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/rmvb"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/avi"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/mkv"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/3gpp*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/mp4"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/mpeg*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/sdp"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.3gp*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.dvd*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.dolby*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.rn-realmedia*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-iso9660-image"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-extension-mp4"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-flac"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-matroska"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-mpegURL"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-quicktimeplayer"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/xspf+xml"/>
            <data android:mimeType="misc/ultravox"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:scheme="ftp"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3g2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3gp"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3gp2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3gpp"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.amv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.asf"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.avi"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.divx"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.drc"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.dv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.f4v"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.flv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.gvi"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.gxf"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ismv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.iso"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m1v"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m2v"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m2t"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m2ts"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mkv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mov"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp2v"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp4"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp4v"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m4v"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpe"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpeg"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpeg1"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpeg2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpeg4"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpg"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpv2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mts"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mtv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mxf"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mxg"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.nsv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.nut"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.nuv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ogm"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ogv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ogx"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ps"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rec"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rm"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rmvb"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tod"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ts"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tts"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vob"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vro"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.webm"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wm"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wmv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wtv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xesc"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3G2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3GP"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3GP2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3GPP"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AMV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ASF"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AVI"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.DIVX"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.DRC"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.DV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.F4V"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.FLV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.GVI"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.GXF"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ISMV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ISO"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M1V"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M2V"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M2T"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M2TS"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M3U8"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MKV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MOV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MP2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MP2V"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MP4"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MP4V"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M4V"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPE"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPEG"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPEG1"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPEG2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPEG4"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPG"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPV2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MTS"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MTV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MXF"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MXG"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.NSV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.NUT"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.NUV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.OGM"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.OGV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.OGX"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.PS"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.REC"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.RM"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.RMVB"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.TOD"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.TS"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.TTS"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.VOB"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.VRO"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.WEBM"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.WM"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.WMV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.WTV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.XESC"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3ga"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.a52"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.aac"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ac3"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.adt"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.adts"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.aif"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.aifc"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.aiff"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.amr"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.aob"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ape"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.awb"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.caf"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.dts"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.flac"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.it"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m4a"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m4b"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m4p"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mid"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mka"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mlp"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mod"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpa"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp1"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp3"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpc"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mpga"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.oga"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ogg"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.oma"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.opus"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ra"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ram"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rmi"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.s3m"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.spx"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tta"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.voc"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vqf"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.w64"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wav"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wma"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.wv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xa"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xm"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3GA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.A52"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AAC"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AC3"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ADT"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ADTS"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AIF"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AIFC"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AIFF"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AMR"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AOB"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.APE"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AWB"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.CAF"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.DTS"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.FLAC"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.IT"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M4A"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M4B"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M4P"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MID"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MKA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MLP"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MOD"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MP1"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MP2"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MP3"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPC"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.MPGA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.OGA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.OGG"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.OMA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.OPUS"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.RA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.RAM"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.RMI"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.S3M"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.SPX"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.TTA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.VOC"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.VQF"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.W64"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.WAV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.WMA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.WV"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.XA"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.XM"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="org.hd.ghost.audio.AudioService"/>
    <receiver android:name="org.hd.ghost.PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:label="VLC mini player" android:name="org.hd.ghost.widget.VLCAppWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/vlcwidget"/>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="org.hd.ghost.RemoteControlClientReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            <action android:name="org.videolan.vlc.remote.PlayPause"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:label="RecyclerViewTestActivity" android:name="android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity"/>
</application>
```

Comment: do you have those internal packages after ghost.gui?

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: what is your original package name? that's right ~ give us log msgs

Comment: @RaviSravanKumar DO you mean the packages that can't be resolved? Than yes I have them and they were working fine before changing package name. Only the packages that are with changed package name are throwing a warning, else are working fine am pretty sure it's something to do with the changed name.

Comment: @JohnJoe There's no error in the project it get's compiled successfully and only crashes when i run the app on a device. I don't know where else do I have to change the package name in the project.

Comment: @BruceWayne can you post  a screen shot of the project structure instead of the above image?

Comment: I don't think you need to have `org.hd.ghost`. Just write `<activity android:name=".gui.SecondaryActivity"....></activity>`

Comment: @RaviSravanKumar added the strucure image

Comment: You mean to start with just .gui? If yes that still didn't resolve it.

Comment: all cannot be resolved or only secondaryActivity ? If you change your package name to original, the error still exists ?

Comment: @JohnJoe only the ones under gui, and some under ghost can't be resolve(the red ones you can see in above screenshot), no they worked and get resolved successfully with original package name.

Comment: where are your secondaryActivity ? Under which package ? I can't see it on structure 2. It is under audio,browser,dialog or video ?

Comment: Hey i could see something like com in the structure what was it?

Comment: could you pos the complete manifest

Comment: @JohnJoe No it just directly under gui see above and not in a subfolder

Comment: @BruceWayne, please post manifest file

Comment: @RaviSravanKumar Manifest file added

Comment: @HirenPatel added the android manifest

Comment: manifest tags are there just they are not showing up here when i post the entire code @RaviSravanKumar

Comment: The activities are not causing the app to crash it's something else can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done very easily in one step. You don't have to touch AndroidManifest. Instead do the following:

right click on the root folder of your project.
Click "Open Module Setting".
Go to the Flavours tab.
Change the applicationID to whatever package name you want.
 Press OK.
The decoupling of Package Name and Application ID is explained here:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Did you read I mentioned I am using android studio? Because I can't seem to find that flavours tab anywhere in it are you explaining this for Eclipse or IntelliJ that won't be helpful here.

Comment: YES that's the solution for Android studio

Comment: Than there's no flavours tab there under Module only sources,paths and dependencies.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gK7zQBw This is how my module settings look and there's no Flavors tab whatsoever.

Comment: I have the latest version of android studio installed.

Comment: Then please open build.gradle(Module: app).

Add this configuration in gradle file.

 defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'org.hd.ghost'
     
    }

Comment: I mentioned already that I am not using a Gradle build so there's no build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have changed package name **to** `org.hd.ghost` **from** `org.hd.gui.`

So you need to do change all activities name (with new  package name).

**Example:**

**Current**

```
<activity android:name="org.hd.gui.SecondaryActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC"/>
```

**New**

```
<activity android:name="org.hd.ghost.SecondaryActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VLC"/>
```

**Note:** You need to change for all activities.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Actually I changed it from org.videolan.vlc to org.hd.ghost and that SecondaryActivity is in gui folder but it still can't detect it, hovering over the code it shows that cannot resolve symbol 'SecondaryActivity'. This is really weird.

Comment: I tried compiling again but those activities are not causing the app to crash, it's something else and I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

please change your folder name inside kotlin folder(current pakage name).

[image]